# Update MongoDB with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I trying to update a field in `users` collection once a user is logged into the application. But the update query is not working at all.

**users.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var User = require('../models/user');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

router.post('/login', function(req,res,next){
   let promise = User.findOne({email:req.body.email}).exec();

    promise.then(function(doc){
      if(doc) {
        if(doc.isValid(req.body.password)){
           // generate token
           let token = jwt.sign({username:doc.username},'secret', {expiresIn : '3h'});

           setOnlineStatus(doc.username);
        } else {
           return res.status(501).json({message:' Invalid Credentials'});
        }
      } else {
         return res.status(501).json({message:'User email is not registered.'})
      }
    });

    promise.catch(function(err){
      return res.status(501).json({message:'Some internal error'});
    })
})

function setOnlineStatus(username){
   console.log(username); // log the correct username value
   User.update(
      {'username': username},
      {$set: {'status':'Online'}},
   );
}
```

**Model - user.js**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

var schema = new Schema({
    email : {type:String, require:true},
    username: {type:String, require:true},
    password:{type:String, require:true},
    creation_dt:{type:Date, require:true}
});

schema.methods.isValid = function(hashedpassword){
   return  bcrypt.compareSync(hashedpassword, this.password);
}

module.exports = mongoose.model('User',schema);
```

So now the problem is once a request is send to `/login` service, the call to `setOnlineStatus()` is not updating `users` collection with a new field status having value 'online'.

> **NOTE:** Using another service `/register` users are already added to the `users` collection.

I'm a newbie to express and mongodb. So please help me to solve this issue. 
Thank you and answers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to define `status` in the schema as mongoose will ignore it while updating other wise (read: [option: strict](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict))

try adding `status: {type: String}` to your schema

also the `update()` function returns a query (read: [Model.update()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#update_update)) it doesn't update unless you pass a callback or execute it with `.exec()`

`User.update({'username': username}, {$set: {'status':'Online'}}).exec()`

Comment: I tried by adding `.exec()` and still the same. No new field named `status` in `users` collection.

Comment: Oh, didn't notice it, try adding `status: {type: String}` to your schema. you need to define the status property in the `schema` mongoose won't create anything outside this set of property.

Comment: But using [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#behavior) it will automatically create a field if it not exist. Right?

Comment: Don't know about this actually and can't find something about that in the docs either, AFAIK `$set` is just to not overwrite the whole document, and mongoose will ignore anything outside the schema while saving

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and comment. Appreciated.

Comment: you're welcome, updated the answer for more about the schema part too, feel free to read the docs link I mentioned above to know more about it.